# ACCESS/SQL QUERY

Tags: ms-access-2010

Why won't this query work on an access database? It works just fine on a MS SQL Database.

```
    Dim MN As Single = 100
    Dim MX As Single = 200

    sql_Data.Reset()
    sql_DA1 = New SqlDataAdapter("select  * into NEWTABLE from OLDTABLE WHERE DEBIT BETWEEN " & "'" & mn & "'" & "AND" & "'" & mx & "'", sql_con)
    sql_DGV1 = New SqlCommandBuilder(sql_DA1)
    sql_DA1.Fill(sql_Data)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Debit` is numeric, thus:

```
"select * into NEWTABLE from OLDTABLE where DEBIT between " & mn & " and " & mx & ""
```